# Average Time on While Loop

Tags: python, time, python-3.x

I've got a function that measures the time it takes for someone to answer a multiplication sum, but I want to be able to show the **average** time the user takes once they've finished using the function (it's on a while loop). Here is the function:

```
def withTimer():
    playAgain = "yes"
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    while playAgain == "yes":
        total = total + 1
        random1 = random.choice(tablesUsed)
        random2 = random.randint(1, 12)
        realAnswer = random1 * random2
        start = time.time()
        humanAnswer = int(input("What is the answer to this multiplication sum?\n" + str(random1) + " * " + str(random2) + "\n"))
        if realAnswer == humanAnswer:
            elapsed = round((time.time() - start), 1)
            correct = correct + 1
            score = str(int(correct / total * 100)) + "%"
            if elapsed < 2:
                print("Congratulations, you got it correct in " + str(elapsed) + " seconds!\nThat is a very good time!\nScore: " + score)
            else:
                print("Congratulations, you got it correct in " + str(elapsed) + " seconds!\nNow work on your time.\nScore: " + score)            
        else:
            score = str(int(correct / total * 100)) + "%"
            print("Unforunately, you got this one incorrect, the actual answer was " + str(realAnswer) + ".\nScore: " + score)
        elapsed1 = 
        playAgain = input("Do you wish to play again? (yes or no)\n")
        if playAgain == "yes":
            settings()
        else:
            print("Thank you for practicing your multiplication tables\nwith me\nFinal Score: " + score + "\nAverage Time: " + averageTime)
```

I've written the averageTime variable to show were I want the average time to be displayed.
I have tried this:

```
if realAnswer == humanAnswer:
            elapsed = round((time.time() - start), 1)
            times = times.append(elapsed)
```

where I have defined the variable `times = []`, and `global times` in another function, but that produces the error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'append', line 26
```

Please help me try and understand what's going on, and a solution!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I figure I might have to create a list that inserts 'elapsed' at 'total'. Am I correct?

Comment: You've imported time and then have a variable *called* time?? Don't you think the poor ickle python might get a bit confused??

Comment: Oh sorry @Vorsprung, the variable is actually called `times`, but that's still probably a bad name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a list of the elapsed times and then calculate the average by summing all the elapsed times and dividing by the number of items in the list, however you don't need to. As long as you keep a running total of the elapsed time, the average time to answer will just be the total elapsed time divided by the total number of answers.

The following version of your program calculates the average in both of these ways and displays both to show that the results are the same either way.

```
import time,random

def withTimer():
    playAgain = "yes"
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    totalTime = 0
    etime = []
    while playAgain[0] == "y":
        total = total + 1
        random1 = random.randint(1, 12)
        random2 = random.randint(1, 12)
        realAnswer = random1 * random2
        start = time.time()
        humanAnswer = int(input("What is the answer to this multiplication sum?\n" + str(random1) + " * " + str(random2) + "\n"))
        if realAnswer == humanAnswer:
            elapsed = round((time.time() - start), 1)
            etime.append(elapsed)
            correct = correct + 1
            score = str(int(correct / total * 100)) + "%"
            if elapsed < 2:
                print("Congratulations, you got it correct in " + str(elapsed) + " seconds!\nThat is a very good time!\nScore: " + score)
            else:
                print("Congratulations, you got it correct in " + str(elapsed) + " seconds!\nNow work on your time.\nScore: " + score)            
        else:
            score = str(int(correct / total * 100)) + "%"
            print("Unforunately, you got this one incorrect, the actual answer was " + str(realAnswer) + ".\nScore: " + score)
        totalTime += elapsed
        playAgain = input("Do you wish to play again? (yes or no)\n")
    averageTime = totalTime / total
    averageTime1 = sum(etime) / len(etime)
    if playAgain[0] != "y":
        print("Thank you for practicing your multiplication tables\nwith me\nFinal Score: " + score + "\nAverage Time: " + str(averageTime) + " AverageTime1 = "  + str(averageTime))


withTimer()
```